# Need to create a picklist formula ...but the results needs to write to another field

Tags: formula, picklist

I'm trying to create a formula using a pick list that will render the output of a revenue field based on the method of calculation(Method_of_Revenue_Calculation__c).

Here is what I have. I keep getting an error "Extra ElseIf

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( Method_of_Revenue_Calculation__c , "Manual"), Projected_Annualized_Amount__c)

ELSEIF 

(ISPICKVAL( Method_of_Revenue_Calculation__c , "Lineitem Rollups"), Proj_Gross_Revenue_over_Term__c)
```

Comment: Those field names probably shouldn't be in quotes. Is this a Currency or Text field?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use elseif in a formula, you have to do a nested if statement.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the nested `IF` statements using the details given by @Max232?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Jagular provided a perfect example, if you don't want a default result, when it is neither value, then keep the quotes empty "".

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce IF formula is defined as follows:

"IF (logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)"

There is no ""ELSIF" function, your formula will need to look something like this:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( Method_of_Revenue_Calculation__c, "Manual"), Projected_Annualized_Amount__c, 
IF(ISPICKVAL( Method_of_Revenue_Calculation__c, "Lineitem Rollups"), Proj_Gross_Revenue_over_Term__c), "???")
```

You will need to define the "???" case where the method of calculation is neither "Manual" or "Lineitem Rollups".